# 'template with C linkage' error when using template keyword in main.cpp

Tags: c++, templates, g++, linkage

In my main.cpp, I create multiple objects of self-defined classes, e.g.:

```
#include "device_manager.hpp"
DeviceManager deviceManager; //compiles and works just fine
```

However, when I try to implement a simple template just below in the same main.cpp:

```
template <typename T>
inline T max(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

I get:

```
template with C linkage main.cpp line 35    C/C++ Problem
```

Seems like the compiler fails to understand the *template* keyword. I did not add any *extern "C"* blocks inside my main.cpp. I have tried using gnu++14 compiler (C++14 + gnu extensions) and gnu++11 for compiling my C++ code and gnu11 for compiling C code inside my C-to-C++ converted project. What could possibly go wrong with understanding the *template* keyword?

EDIT:
The project was generated as a C project which I later converted to a C++ project using an IDE tool, also changing main.c to main.cpp. Since then, I could declare my class objects in main.cpp without problems, but when I try to use the *template* keyword in main.cpp, I get the aforementioned error as though it was inside extern "C" statement (but I didn't put it there).

C compiler command: arm-atollic-eabi-gcc  -c, compiler: gnu11

C++ compiler command: arm-atollic-eabi-g++  -c, compiler: gnu++14

Linker command: arm-atollic-eabi-g++
(I am on an ARM embedded system, writing in Atollic TrueStudio IDE)

Comment: This is C++ not C.  I removed the extraneous tag.

Comment: @jwdonahue The question mentions that both C code and C++ are compiled, and apparently the problem is that linker/compiler handles C++ as C. Are you sure about the tag being extraneous?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  You might also want to show how you compile/link.

Comment: Question already edited. I will be happy to answer more detailed questions on my problem

Answer (score 2):

the "C linkage" part makes me suspect that you might not close the

```
extern "C" {
//...
}
```

declaration in your header file.

this is the error exactly the code like this will produce:

```
extern "C" {
template <typename T>
inline T max(T a, T b) {
  return a > b ? a : b;
}
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but as I wrote, checked all possible `extern "C"` blocks and this is not the case. Still, declaring classes objects just a line above in main.cpp works fine for me

Comment: please, do me a favor, and remove that header; if template compiles OK without it, there MUST be something you missed inside that header (or transitively in any header it includes).

Comment: That might be a case with an `extern "C"` lost somewhere in files included from main.h, just began tracking it

Comment: That apparently solved the issue. There was a block of `extern "C" {` not closed with a `}` in a library (yes) included file. Beware of your included libraries